# How to write a converter class? How to efficiently write mapping rules?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, mapping, converters

I have a quite big class A with lots of members, and i have a quite big class B
that can be built when having an A object. An A object can be built when having
a B object. I need both of them, as A is a kind of ViewModel, which has validation
and B is a graphical description, which can be plotted easily.

How to do this conversion?

here is an example, to illustrate what i want to do:

```
class A
{
    string s;
    string t;
    string u;
    string v;

    enum a;
    enum b;
    enum c;
    enum d;
    enum e;

    Dictionary<enum, string> dict;
}


class B
{
    string someString; // is essentially A.a + A.b + A.c + A.s with some rules.
    int someValue; // is essentially dict.TryGetValue(enum.Entry);
    string anotherString;
    // ... and lots of others
}
```

Of course it is simple to do some mapping, and build up a B object,
and it is not very hard to write plain B => A mapping by inverting 
the rules of building A => B

**So the questions are:**

- Are there any well known patterns to achieve that?
- Is there a default C# way of doing such things?

Writing down plain something like that seems not to fit,
it ends up in hundreds of lines of code.

I thought about some kind of converter classes for the parts,
like SomeStringConverter, SomeValueConverter, ...

- How can i abstract the needed members of A together with
   the rules to do the mapping.
- How can i write those rules to have the easiest possible
   way of doing A => B and B => A.

**Edit:**
Pattern here is meant as "Best practises" and not as "GoF design patterns"

SomeString in the B class is some kind of "selector", it selects drawing
options, it is always 25 characters long and the enums in class A choose
those characters, but not 1 on 1 in most cases.

Lets say for example: A.a = "Filled", A.b = "SingleCoordinate", A.c = "DrawHints"
will result in something like SomeString =

```
 "Y**D***RR****---***---***"
```

i.e. the combination is important to get such an string, but from the combiniation
you can derive the enums that have to be set in an A object.

**Edit2:**

I'm especially interested in ways of using my mapping rules for both ways, i.e. 
A.a = "Filled" combined with A.b = "SingleCoordinate" combinded with A.c = "DrawHints" will result in (partial string) `"Y**D***RR"`, and that partial string also means that
A.a has to be set to "Filled" and so on.

Comment: Just have one of the classes inherit the other.

Comment: Think that is not the best way, as one has the validation for input and the other, despite being totally different in composition, is easy for plotting, but the contents are similar, but mapped. But clearly, I already thought of having some PONO class holding the data and two converters, resulting in A and B and converter for A => PONO and B => PONO. Perhaps that is the way to go.

Comment: It's POCO, since this is .net after all :)

Comment: Of course, you are right! thought of some .NET object...

Comment: can you give an example of what "someString" from B would look like?

Comment: of course, i'll edit in the question

Comment: could it be a fit for custom serializer/deserializer? i.e. both object serialize/deserialize to a common format...

Comment: Nice idea! But how to use the mapping rules for two ways? perhaps this should be another question, so...

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34118/Lambda-Converter-Pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to solve this problem:

1. Wrote a BiMap (with the help of older SOs on that issue).
2. Inserted the Mapping into it (all value combinations in Key, the resulting key in the "Value", together with a BitArray which specifies the indices of the string that are
   defined by that mapping.
3. Wrote some code to calculate a resulting overall string from it, as the mapping
   will just give partial strings.
4. The one-to-one mappings were trivial.

That way I could use the mappings in both ways. Given a string, I still have a quite
expensive search (as I have to compute the stored string utilizing the BitArray as a mask)

At the moment it seems to work very good, but I'm not finished yet.

Thank you all for your very good ideas and approaches! Perhaps AutoMapper can do
this, but I do not have much time at the moment to read and try out a new technology.

**If anybody can provide some relevant examples on how to do this on Automapper,
I will accept it as an answer (as I already love AutoMapper).**

Examples like lets say: 3 enums with 5 values to one fixed length string
one fixed length string to 3 enum with 5 values (the reverse of the above).

as an example:

```
A.a && B.o && C.y ==> "**A**********************"
A.a && B.p && C.y ==> "**B**********************"
A.b && B.o && C.y ==> "*****X*******************"
A.b && B.o && C.z ==> "*****W*******************"
```

Can Automapper achieve such things?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like A is more of the Data Model and B is more of the View Model. I don't think there's a generally accepted "pattern" for this kind of instance—mainly because the reasons behind this kind of pairing vary widely and the best pattern is heavily dependent on intended use.

That said, since they're so tightly tied together, I'd tend to make one class subordinate to the other. In this case, since A is more straightforward, I'd probably use A as the data container for B. i.e. Have a private member A as a field in class B and all the properties in class B reference class A directly—updating properties in A rather than having their own private fields behind. You could then have a public property on class B that exposes the private member of class A if needed. I'd probably keep that read-only, but that's probably not really important (depending on your use of class B and any possible bound relationships). To go the other way, I'd then create a constructor on class B that accepts class A as a parameter. The passed value of A would then be assigned to the private class A member on class B.

The upshot of all that is to maintain class A's ignorance of class B—which becomes useful if you have a true use case for a ViewModel situation. If you determine that class A is the truer ViewModel in your needs, then reverse the above so that class B is the one ignorant of class A.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, indeed one is near the datamodel, whereas the other *is* a kind of ViewModel (not in the sense of MVVM, but it can be plotted directly). I have now applied a solution, probably not the best of all, but one that works and has not that much overhead of applying new mappings and is easy to maintain (having the mappings in A or B will have excessive overhead, having two different places to change). Thank you! +1

Comment: Sure thing. Glad it made sense. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any well known patterns to achieve that?

It depends on what you mean by pattern. The [`Decorator`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [`Adapter`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) patterns come to mind, but neither is meant for wholesale mapping of types to different types.

> Is there a default C# way of doing such things?

No, there isn't. But libraries like [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) sure make life easier.

Comment: +1, This is basically something I was writing. Really, you're looking at marking up your class with a bunch of attributes so that other classes can inspect it with reflection and act on that metadata.

Comment: @MareInfinitus - it is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, but automapper will not parse a string for you. A custom parser looks like the best option for you.

Comment: What i want to know is, if building such a custom parser, are there any best practises.

Comment: @MareInfinitus - Not that I know of. Use the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) in your parser to keep track of where you are and what transitions are allowed (the HTML Agilty Pack parses HTML and is open source - a good placed to see how it is done).

Comment: A state pattern seems like way over-engineering. I don't see why using Automapper with custom mappings isn't the answer here. You can write lamba expressions to define your "parsing" rules.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - Not sure I follow. From the comments in the code sample, I understand the OP wants to parse a string to a set of enumerations.

Comment: I know of automapper, but have not used it myself. I will read about it now.

Comment: @Oded: this is exactly what is necessary for the B => A case.

Comment: @Oded - isn't that (string to set of enums) just a custom value resolver? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - I think you are oversimplifying. The example from the OP involved 5 enumerations - I don't know that creating a custom value resolver would be any easier than a custom parser. I could be wrong. This is not an aspect of Automapper I am very familiar with.

Comment: The real classes are somewhat larger. It is some legacy code, but an instance of an B object is something over 4 kb(!) when properly filled.

Answer (score 0):

Factory + possibly Facade

You want to coordinate building a B from an A or an A from a B. This argues that you need complex logic to do so.

To build B from A, either implement as a static method on B (Factory), or create a new class C that inherits from B, and takes an A as argument to its constructor (Facade).

Factory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern (Not an exact match for your situation)

Facade: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Pattern_-_Facade (not an exact match either)

Comment: As you already stated, are those design patterns no exact match on that problem. perhaps there are any best pratices for c#.

Comment: I think that Factory matches well. It's just that usually Factory is used for much more complex construction, and so most descriptions and examples will replect that. To my mind any system where an A and a B is passed to a method, then configued as desired, will qualify as "Factory", even if the instances are constructed elsewhere. Still I think most people will think of Factory as a "smart constructor", and so expect that the instances are constructed inside the factory.

Comment: Factory solves only a little part of the overall problem, especially as there is no possibility to reuse mapping rules.

Comment: Then I think perhaps you are looking for "Builder. One class specifies the structure of the product, the other the concrete expression of it. The usual example is an abstract description of a document (say, in HTML) that can be rendered in several ways (strip formatting for a text only display, format as full HTML in a browser, convert to RTF...)

Comment: Single design patterns rarely tell you how to implement your entire program. You will usually have to apply several. They are really quite tactical when it comes down to it. In this case then: Builder to specify the relationship between A and B, Factory to create them, and configure them properly for interaction. To get your reuse of rules, have the builder from B to A understand and reverse a builder form A to B (or vice-versa)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: Thank you for your comments! As mentioned previous, this question is not the search for the right mixture of GoF patterns. I want to hear about best practices on mapping different types, especially if they are that big (as mentioned, an object of B is about 4kb). Applying different sets of mapping rules is errorprone and a null-gain job. But i can't figure out a clear C# solution for this at the moment, as for example is quite simple in C++... have to investigate more on that.

Comment: GoF patterns are a class of best practices. I am not mentioning the Builder pattern because it's GoF. I am mentioning it because it's best practice when you want to map a description (instance of A or B) to a way of expressing it (instance of B or A) with the "mappers" as re-usable, clearly delineated entities. I can't write your code for you, as only you really understand the issue. I can only advise you on how to organize it. Perhaps if you gave an example of how it is supposedly easy in C++?

Comment: Of course GoF are best practise. I know them (and have used most of them on a daily basis), but here I need something different, a new approach. In C++ mapping is easier for me, as I have a heavy background on C++ (12 years of work with it), but only about a year in C# 4.0

Answer (score 0):

A couple thoughts:

A) Change B into an interface which A implements. This would allow you to "map" B's properties directly to A's properties without having to recreate them. In cases where B has a property that A is not supposed to have (or a property which combines several of A's), you can set the access modifier to private* - meaning the property will only be visible through the interface (so as not to confuse or clutter implementations of A).

B) Use a pseudo adapter/wrapper pattern. B, given a constructor parameter of type A, can refer back to A's properties, etc. Where B differs, it can implement its own logic.

Mapping between two complex objects requires some complex thinking. There will always be special cases, side effects and choices requiring thought and balancing of pros and cons. (For example, converting between a string and an int introduces all kinds of question - what to do with the thousand's separator, how to handle different cultures, etc.) From reading your specific circumstances, I do not see an easy or quick way to handle the mapping - you'll have on a method based on all the factors involved, probably too many to post here.

EDIT:
* I should note that this is what I've done in several VB projects. I assume this is legal in C#, but I've not tried it.

Comment: I think i will go for an external DTO, which will be used by both of those objects, and the mapping is done A <==> DTO <==> B. Feels the most natural at the moment. Just lots of work to achieve something "quite simple".

Comment: If it was so simple, you probably wouldn't be getting paid to do it. (Although, maybe you aren't getting paid anyway!)

Comment: It is not simple in a way to write it down and everything is done. The mapping part is still there ;)