# Merge object #1 to object #2 for all existing properties of object #2

Tags: c#

I have a rather verbose object with a lot of properties which I use to transport data to a SQL database. I would now like to provide a "light" version of this object that only uses some properties of the verbose one.

I'm using the light objects to provide through a REST api, and the verbose ones to transport the data, so ideally I could reverse the process as well (overwriting properties of verbose object with existing properties of light object, then save to database).

All these properties will have the same data types, as long as they exist in the light object.

Simple example:

```
class Verbose {
  public string email;
  public Guid id;
}

class Simple {
  public string email;
  // don't show Guid
}
```

Now I want to transform all objects of type Verbose to type Simple, ditching all unnecessary properties - is there a simple way to do this?

Ideally this should be reversible as well.

Comment: Could you not have a Verbose.ToSimple() method which creates and returns a new Simple object with the appropriate data?  And vice versa (I guess you would need to have default/empty values though)

Comment: That's an option as well, but then I'd have to change this every time I change to database object. My goal is to just define the properties I want made public in the Simple object type and then delegate the mapping from Verbose to Simple automatically.

Comment: edited in a link in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a constructor that takes a verbose object 
and vice versa.

```
public Verbose(Simple simple)
{
    this.id = Guid.NewGuid();
    this.email = simple.email;
}

public Simple(Verbose verbose)
{
    this.email = verbose.email;
}
```

That way, you have all the conversion in one place,
at least each conversion direction.

This question here might be of interest for you:
[How to write a converter class? How to efficiently write mapping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214401/how-to-write-a-converter-class-how-to-efficiently-write-mapping-rules)

**EDIT AS IMPORTANT TO OP**

Verbose => Simple

If `Simple` is a subset of `Verbose`, just derive `Verbose` from `Simple`.
no conversion needed here.

Verbose ***IS*** a Simple then.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid - I'd have to assign each property manually.

Comment: automagic property assigning will have many traps. especially when using reflection you will see that the performance is not very good.

Comment: I think not in this case - all datatypes are the same in both objects.

Comment: What do you try to avoid? Manually writing a conversion or automagic traps?

Comment: Manual conversion. Can you elaborate which traps might exist?

Comment: for example two properties with the same name, but different type, or two properties that should match, but do not have the same name. etc.

Comment: Edited in a link that might be of interest for you

Comment: Those cases would not happen. The verbose object is one generated by ADO and the Simple one is just a light version of that, which excludes certain sensitive information.

Comment: Ah, I see. Edited in a solution to that into my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14390/discussion-between-xymak1y-and-mare-infinitus)

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to traverse objects and reading their property values.
In your class add this function

```
private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetValidInfoes()
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo info in GetType().GetProperties())
    {
         if (info.CanWrite)
            yield return info;
    }
}
```

Add this loop somewhere where it makes sense to you.

```
foreach (var item in GetValidInfoes())
{
     var source = myobject.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name);
     if (source != null)
        item.SetValue(this, source.GetValue(item.Name, item.PropertyType), null);
}
```

Comment: This depends on the property name. And the performance hit will definitly be an issue with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). If you will not use flattening it can be reversible.

Comment: I will definitely look into that, thanks! Unless someone knows of an even simpler solution without the need for an external library.

Comment: The advantage of external library is that its authors dedicated their time and put a lot of effort in making it work right and fast. Don't invent the wheel.

Comment: I agree, but I'm trying to avoid using a large library if I only need a small part of it. I will consider it though, so thank you very much!